What is the "all" method that works on a VHDL "line" variable?
Here is the code; it works, but I want to understand why:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library std;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb_17 is    
end entity;

architecture beh of tb_17 is    
begin

  process
    variable L : line;
  begin
    write(L, string'("Hello"));
    report "   this is size of the line: " & integer'image(L.all'length);
    report "   this is text of the line: " & L.all;
    report "this is the first character: " & L.all(1);
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;

What exactly does "all" mean when applied to a line, and why does it work?  I have not seen any book on VHDL so far that describes this, but someone told me about it.
My question is, why does L.all work? The L is not a record. What part of VHDL makes L.all possible?

'all' means 'import everything' in VHDL

This question is about the line variable, where I do l.all

please clarify your question ... writing a comment is not a clarification

A standard is a terrible thing to ignore. IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.3 Selected  names "For a selected name that is used to denote the object designated by an access value, the suffix shall be the reserved word all. The prefix shall belong to an access type." Line is an access type for a string. the access value as the prefix of an access type when taken with the suffix all denotes the value of the object being accessed. Access types aren't synthesis eligible.

This question is about simulation only testbench only code. So basically what this means is that the "all" does dereference of a pointer since the access type is a pointer?

Cute example.   It would have been more clear what was happening if L was created by:   L := new string'("Hello") ;    Then you would clearly understand everything here is about pointers.

The first use can be removed since length can be applied directly to line. From page 311 of the standard:

  process
    variable L : line;
  begin
    write(L, string'("Hello"));
    report "   this is size of the line: " & integer'image(L'length);
    report "   this is text of the line: " & L.all;
    report "this is the first character: " & L.all(1);
    wait;
  end process;

But the two following ones need to be there for the concatenation operator with strings to work properly:

Note:    this is size of the line: 5


Note:    this is text of the line: Hello


Note: this is the first character: H

Since line is a pointer to a string:
package TEXTIO is
    type LINE is access string;

The .all provides the contents of the reference:


But the L'length should also not work since it will end up giving the length of the pointer rather than the contents that are referenced right?

@gyuunyuu See reference added to the answer
